# Multiselect rendered as tags in documents

Tags: pimcore

In Data Objects we have the possibility to render multiselects as tags. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality in documents?

We have tried the following but nothing seems to change:

```
<?= $this->multiselect($filter, [
    "width" => 200,
    "height" => 150,
    'renderType' => 'tags',
    "store" => \InteliveBundle\Model\Utils::getSelectOptions($filter),
    "reload" => false,
    'class' => "editmode-cssid",
    'htmlspecialchars' => false,
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you have the following configuration options:

- **store**    array   Key/Value pairs for the available options.
- **width**    integer Width of a generated block in editmode
- **height**   integer Height of a generated block in editmode
- **class**    string  A CSS class that is added to the surrounding container
  of this element in editmode

https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Documents/Editables/Multiselect.html

Therefore this feature seems not to be implemented. You can make a feature request in https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore or even better you fork the project, implement this feature and make a merge request.